# Django race condition: code does not fetch newly created records

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am running Django (1.11.20 with `ATOMIC_REQUESTS: True`) and Postgres, and have a Django view that basically does:

```
job = Job(name='hello')
job.save()
files = JobFile.objects.create(job_id=job.id, file='myfile.txt')
```

Most of the time, this works fine. But every so often, another process (that is executed by cron) checks the `JobFile` table and finds it not containing a record for a given existing `Job`, when doing:

```
jobs = Job.objects.filter(timestamp=my_timestamp)
job_files = {}
for jf in JobFile.objects.filter(job__in=jobs):
  try:
    job_files[jf.job_id].add(jf.file)
  except KeyError:
    job_files[jf.job_id] = set([jf.file])

for job in jobs:
  files = job_files[job.id] if job.id in job_files else set()
  print('Job {} found with files {}'.format(job.id, files))

# output when this problem occurs is typically:
# Job found 123 with files set()
```

It reports it found a `Job` without a `JobFile` in the log and errors, and when I check somewhat later the DB contains a `JobFile` just fine.

I am scratching my head as to why it doesnt find `JobFile` records, and now I investigated and found that in the lastest occurrences of this problem, the cron process initiated about 0.1s before record creation and finished closely after, which made me suspicious that there is some sort of timing problem. But my (limited) understanding would be that when this is all in a single view, `ATOMIC_REQUESTS` would ensure that both objects exist. My other suspect is the `create` method but that seems to return nicely after calling save according to its [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.11.x/django/db/models/query.py#L387). What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure every `Job` has a `JobFile`?

Comment: thanks, edited to addres your valid points about no jobs and no jobfiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a race condition. Django and Postgres use [`READ COMMITTED`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/databases/#isolation-level) isolation level, which means that queries in your cron job will see new objects once the transactions have been committed.

I've added comments to your code to explain the issue

```
# This doesn't cause a query because Django querysets are lazy
jobs = Job.objects.filter(timestamp=my_timestamp)
job_files = {}
# This fetches the jobfiles for the jobs existing at this point
for jf in JobFile.objects.filter(job__in=jobs):
  try:
    job_files[jf.job_id].add(jf.file)
  except KeyError:
    job_files[jf.job_id] = set([jf.file])

# During the loop above, extra jobs and jobfiles are saved to the database

# This line causes the jobs queryset to be evaluated. It includes the new jobs
for job in jobs:
  files = job_files[job.id] if job.id in job_files else set()
  print('Job {} found with files {}'.format(job.id, files))
```

You can avoid the error by using `list()` to force the jobs queryset to be evaluated at the beginning of the script.

```
jobs = list(Job.objects.filter(timestamp=my_timestamp))
```

Comment: This explanation makes perfect sense, I never realized ALL of `JobFile` was fetched there. It will take me a while to see no errors occurring (should probably fix a way to make this testable). Thanks!

Comment: *I never realized ALL of JobFile was fetched there* - my wording wasn't as clear as it could be. It's fetching the matching `JobFiles`s that exist at that point. The issue is that jobs used in `.filter(`job__in=jobs)` and `for job in jobs` are not necessarily the same.

Comment: I indeed understood your last sentence, but does that mean that `jobs` is evaluated twice, once in `filter(job__in=jobs)` and then again in the iteration, or does django form some kind of `JOIN`?

Comment: Using `list()` as I suggested forces `jobs` to be evaluated once. Before, the `filter(job__in=jobs)` would be a subquery, and then `jobs` would be fetched when you called `for job in jobs`. You can [check the queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running) that Django is using yourself. It would be useful to read the docs on [when querysets are evaluated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated).